# Pycharm runtime error

Tags: linux, python, pycharm

I encountered an error when I tried to run my Python code. 
This is my development environment:

- OS : Linux Mint,
- IDE : Pycharm

whole error image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGPzf.png)

this is the error messages as you can see on the image:

```
/home/graminux/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python /home/graminux/Desktop/myPyCode/LSTM_price_prediction.py
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007ff05310a740 (most recent call first):

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try to recreate the venv and probably reinstall the base as well (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834381/i-broke-python-what-can-i-do). The interpreter seems to be corrupted.